# PHP script errors

Tags: php, mysql

I have written the 2 scripts below for registering a new user and fetching data from SQL database to my Java code on Android studio, however I have may errors on both due to parsing errors and incorrect parameters.

Can anyone help?

Thankyou in advance.

Warning: mysqli_connect() expects parameter 5 to be long, string given in /home/a1051468/public_html/register.php on line 2

Warning: mysqli_prepare() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, null given in /home/a1051468/public_html/register.php on line 9

Warning: mysqli_stmt_bind_param() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_stmt, null given in /home/a1051468/public_html/register.php on line 10

Warning: mysqli_stmt_execute() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_stmt, null given in /home/a1051468/public_html/register.php on line 11

Warning: mysqli_stmt_close() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_stmt, null given in /home/a1051468/public_html/register.php on line 13

Warning: mysqli_close() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, null given in /home/a1051468/public_html/register.php on line 15

```
<?php
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","my_user","my_user","my_password","my_db");

$name = $_POST["name"];
$age = $_POST["age"];
$password = $_POST["password"];
$username = $_POST["username"];

$statement = mysqli_prepare($con, "INSERT INTO User (name, age, username, password) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?) ");
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($statement, "siss", $name, $age, $username, $password);
mysqli_stmt_execute($statement);

mysqli_stmt_close($statement);

mysqli_close($con);
```

?>

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING in /home/a1051468/public_html/FetchUserData.php on line 2

```
<?php
$con=mysqli_connect('localhost','my_user','my_user','my_password','my_db');

$password = $_POST['password'];
$username = $_POST['username'];

$statement = mysql_prepare($con, "SELECT * FROM User WHERE username = ? AND password = ?");

mysqli_stmt_bind_param($statement, "ss", $username, $password);
mysqli_stmt_execute($statement);

mysqli_stmt_store_result($statement);
mysqli_stmt_bind_result($statement, $userID, $name, $age, $username, $password);

$user = array();

while(mysqli_stmt_fetch($statment)){
    $user[name] = $name;
    $user[age] = $age;
    $user[username] = $username;
    $user[password] = $password;
}

echo json_encode($user);

    mysqli_stmt_close($statement);

mysqli_close($con);
```

?>

Comment: More details please, what is the error you're getting?

Comment: @oliver_13 Don't add the code as comments. Edit your original post and format the code correctly.

Comment: appologies, i have updated the question with the errors @user2610529

Comment: Your mysqli_connect is wrong you have put the username two times in the arguments

Answer (score 0):

You have the username twice in mysqli_connect: `mysqli_connect("localhost","my_user","my_user","my_password","my_db");` should be `mysqli_connect("localhost", "my_user", "my_password", "my_db");`

Also in your second script you have mysql_prepare on line 7 instead of mysqli_prepare.